# MonoDroid and Google Maps: package com.google.android.maps does not exist

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

I am having trouble to incorporate Google Maps in an adroid app created with MonoDroid. I am using the MonoDevelop IDE.

I referenced the Mono.Android.GoogleMaps package (I noticed that the version is 0.0.0.0).
I created a MapActvity called LocationMapActivity. When I try to build the app I get the following error in LocationMapActivity.java: **package com.google.android.maps does not exist**.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Make sure not to forget to set the correct target framework after installing the Google API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Maps library is not included with the base Android SDK, so I'm guessing that you haven't installed the Google APIs add-on. Xamarin has some documentation [available here](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API#Configuring_Maps_API_Prerequisites) with details on what you need to do to install the add-on and set up an emulator that includes support for it.

Comment: Link seems not to work anymore. http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API#Creating_an_Emulator_with_Google_APIs